# Make a function pointer in the kernel pointing to our own

Tags: c, linux-kernel, exploit, shellcode

Assume I have a made a function pointer in the kernel pointing to my own function in the user space code. Let's say on [line 626](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=2.4.37#L602) of `<mm/filemap.c>` in kernel 2.4.37, since the `writepage` function pointer points to my own designed `writepage` in the user space, can I get the root shell now or do anything bad?
I have already verified `writepage` in the kernel points to my own designed `writepage` now, here is my own `writepage`:

```
int evil_writepage(struct page *page)
{
    printf("You've done bad things!!\n");
    /* To do, can I get root shell in here? Or anything bad*/
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You're likely going to get a kernel panic running `printf` and `exit` while running as the kernel...

Comment: @tangrs Thanks for your reply. I see it prints out the message "You've done bad things", that's why I'm sure the `writepage` in the kernel has pointed to my own designed `evil_writepage` in my user space. But I don't get what you mean. Could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: @tangrs You mean if we run `printf`in the kernel mode, we will get a panic, right? I understand that. But why am I still able to use `printf` in my `evil_writepage` since I have redirected the `writepage` function pointer in the kernel pointing to my own `evil_writepage`? Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Malware development. Please go away.  Please don't come back.

Comment: `printf` will eventually cause `write`, which probably faults if you're already in kernel mode. I would be very suspicious if this worked at all. If you really want to see if this works, try accessing some kernel addresses from your replaced function - if your program dies, you must not be executing in-kernel.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @nneonneo Could you possibly give me an example for accessing some kernel addresses from the replaced function? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward, classic way to obtain root permissions during a kernel exploit is to call the function sequence

```
commit_creds(prepare_kernel_cred(0));
```

after obtaining code-exec in kernel mode. To do this, you'll need to look up the addresses for `commit_creds` and `prepare_kernel_cred`. Doing so is beyond the scope of this answer, but it can usually be done by parsing `/proc/kallsyms` (if running without `kptr_restrict`) or by parsing the kernel symbol table from your hijacked callback.

After running this code, your process will have root privileges, but you still need to return to userspace safely (i.e. without triggering any crashes on your way back). From `writepage`, you can get back safely by just returning from your hijacked function, since you haven't destroyed any critical kernel structures.

Once back in user mode, you can just run e.g. `execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", NULL], [NULL])` to get a root shell.